# What is the fundamental difference between an anchor tag and a $http.get?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, twitter-oauth

I'm making a web app using angular, and I was wondering what the difference was when I click an a tag like so...

`<a href="/auth/twitter" target="_self" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Twitter OAuth</a>`

compared to clicking a button that fires a function in my services.

`$http.get('/auth/twitter')`

The latter causes a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error and the first doesn't. So there's something different between them but I can't figure out or search what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use $http.get for API/AJAX calls and the anchor for redirections.

The reason is because an $http.get is expecting a result that is returned by the URL, like raw JSON data, and anchor not.

Since you only need a redirection, you can't use the $http.get method and should use an anchor.

Comment: Could you expand on why?

Comment: I don't know why that didn't come to me at first. But that makes a lot of sense! Now I at least know the difference I can research the difference between both type of "get" requests. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) makes an asynchronous 'GET' request using the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object. The `'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error message is sent because your app makes a [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) to Twitter.

The

```
<a href="/auth/twitter" target="_self" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Twitter OAuth</a>
```

makes a synchronous 'GET' request for the resource at `"/auth/twitter"`.

Comment: Sooo.. what's the difference between an AJAX GET and a regular GET?